# Fatal: Failed to read genesis file: open genesis.json: permission denied

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I try to init private network and run this command:

`geth init genesis.json --datadir=ethdata/`

Also, I try to run the same with `sudo`

`sudo geth init genesis.json --datadir=ethdata/`

But the result is no different.

My `genesis.json` file:

```
{
   "config":{
      "chainId":0,
      "homesteadBlock":0,
      "eip155Block":0,
      "eip158Block":0
   },
   "alloc":{
      
   },
   "coinbase":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   "difficulty":"0x20000",
   "extraData":"",
   "gasLimit":"0x2fefd8",
   "nonce":"0x0000000000000042",
   "mixhash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   "parentHash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   "timestamp":"0x00"
}
```

`chmod` numeric value of file:

```
$ stat -c %a genesis.json
777
```

`ls -alu`

```
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 3 narnik users  4096 Jan 10 23:20 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 narnik narnik 4096 Jan 10 23:18 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 narnik users  4096 Jan  9 20:15 ethdata
-rwxrwxr-x 1 narnik narnik  525 Jan 10 23:19 file.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 narnik narnik  525 Jan 10 23:19 genesis.json
```

Also, I tried to reinstall `geth`, but this also did not produce the expected results.

Comment: If the **ethdata** folder is in the root, then, in theory, it should be:
--datadir=/ethdata

Comment: No, `ethdata` in the same folder as `genesis.json` file

Comment: Try to specify the full path for both the **ethdata** folder and **genesis.json**

Comment: The same error with full path to `genesis.json` file and `ethdata` folder.

Comment: Try changing the order of the parameters on the command line like this:
geth --datadir=/opt/rchain/quorum init qnesis.json

Comment: The same. I have tried, it seems, all possible ways, and I do not understand what is the matter. I made the file executable, I made the file read-only and that didn't help either.

Comment: Try to make a copy of the **qnesis.json** file and use it.

Comment: The same error: `Fatal: Failed to read genesis file: open genesis2.json: permission denied
`

Comment: Is this your first time launching an ethereum on *NIX?
Please show the current view of the command line and the contents of the folder in which genesis.jcion is located: ls -alu <folder path>

Comment: I'm was add result of command to question.